# Error while adding Schema to Spark DataFrame loaded from file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-conversion

```
val tableDF = spark.read.option("delimiter",",").csv("/Volumes/Data/ap/click/test.csv")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType, IntegerType}

val schemaTd = StructType(List(StructField("time_id",IntegerType),StructField("week",IntegerType),StructField("month",IntegerType),StructField("calendar",StringType)))

val result = spark.createDataFrame(tableDF,schemaTd)
```

test.csv data sample below

```
6659,951,219,2018-03-25 00:00:00
6641,949,219,2018-03-07 00:00:00
6645,949,219,2018-03-11 00:00:00
6638,948,219,2018-03-04 00:00:00
6646,950,219,2018-03-12 00:00:00
6636,948,219,2018-03-02 00:00:00
6643,949,219,2018-03-09 00:00:00
```

all the columns  except last value are Int type in the file still getting an error

```
scala> result.show
2018-05-20 17:08:54 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of int
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, time_id), IntegerType) AS time_id#23
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, week), IntegerType) AS week#24
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, month), IntegerType) AS month#25
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 3, calendar), StringType), true, false) AS calendar#26
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkSession.scala:589)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of int
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.If$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:288)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should provide schema to `DataFrameReader`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schemaTd = StructType(List(
   StructField("time_id",IntegerType),
   StructField("week",IntegerType),
   StructField("month",IntegerType),
   StructField("calendar",StringType)))

val tableDF = spark.read.option("delimiter",",")
  .schema(schemaTd)
  .csv("/Volumes/Data/ap/click/test.csv")
```

When `Dataset` is created from `RDD[Row]` (I assume your actual code is `spark.createDataFrame(tableDF.rdd, schemaTd)`, otherwise it shouldn't really compile), types have to be consistent with schema. You cannot provide `String` (default type for CSV reader) and declare schema with `IntegerType`.

Comment: Great that helped. So schema can't be changed once declared in .schema? What if i need to change the datatypes of columns? How can I do that?